# Text not updating onto sql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently trying to create a comment section on my website. The code is almost done but I have run into an issue. When submiting the text, it is not going to my database. Here is the code to take the text and send it to MySQL database.

```
<?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';

function setComments($conn) {
     if(isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])){
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid, 
$date, 
$message')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

    }


}
```

If you could provide me with an answer that would be great.

Comment: This is unrelated but you better get the date from the server to prevent manipulation of comment date in the browser e.g. writing a comment last or next week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong quotation marks around the values. You need to quote around each individual variable in the $sql string.

```
<?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';

function setComments($conn) {
    if(isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])){
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid', 
'$date', 
'$message')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

    }


}
```

NOTE: Use parametrized queries. Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) about sql injection.